# Why is Nezuko stronger than regular demons?

Tags: demon-slayer

In manga #83 it is mentioned that

> Nezuko's regeneration speed matches that of an upper moon, and later it's mentioned that it surpasses the regeneration speed of one of the upper moons.

Also, Nezuko has shown to be stronger than an average demon before, when she kicked those strong demon balls for example. Why is Nezuko stronger than regular demons, considering she neither has martial art skills, nor consume humans to get stronger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was referenced by several demons (starting with three-horned demon with clones), that she seems to be strong due to amount and quality of demon blood she was injected with to be turned into a demon. Other possible reasons were not specified so far.

Answer (score 5):

@lentinant Already mentioned one of the reasons why Nezuko is stronger than most other demons. It's because she was able to survive after taking a large amount of blood from Muzan Kibutsuji.

Muzan Kibutsuji may have tried to kill Nezuko by exploding her after injecting a lot of his blood into her veins. But she was somehow able to survive with that much of Muzan's blood, that's what possibly made her a powerful demon.

In one of the episodes, we see Muzan Kibutsuji frightened of Nezuko and Tanjiro's past relitave when he found the same earrings and scar on the face and ears of Tanjiro.

Apart from that, I would say her father was possibly a Demon Slayer too, maybe he was researching rare herbs or plants that could protect humans from becoming flesh eating Demons. He was maybe able to create a vaccine with which a human can control his/her will after becoming a demon too. He could have injected his family with the vaccine because he knew Muzan Kibutsuji would come after him & his family in future.

There may be some limitations on a vaccine, like how it should be injected before becoming a demon.

Answer (score 0):

maybe because she sleeps a lot and she conquered muzan's blood. according to Urokodaki that nezuko regain her strength by sleeping. other demons gain there strength by eating humans. so as long that she sleeps she gaining more and more power.

> especially now that nezuko conquered the sun :)

Comment: Good guess! but her strength comes from the reason the she got injected so much of Muzan's blood and her family blood line is somehow related to the breath of the sun user.

Comment: that one too! according to the manga using breath of the sun tech uses your life force so maybe it's like when you use blood art but since they are a demon the fast regeneration takes it away.

and maybe, we will see a better explanation for the origin why muzan(demon's) exist. maybe it will help to better understand demons